# Solid has same volume when axis of rotation increases?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, wolfram-alpha

I'm working on calculating the volumes of different solids using integration. The problem I'm working on says to find the volume of two solids, one revolved around the line $x = 4$ and the other around the line $x = 8$. When I was checking my answer I noticed that on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), it said that the volume of both solids was the same. Is that correct? Do solids revolved around these two axis really the same? It seems to me that it shouldn't... But if so, is this true for other cases?

[image]

Volume of [solid #1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=revolve+area+between+x+%3D+y%5E%282%2F3%29+and+x+%3D+0+and+y+%3D+8+around+x+%3D+4+from+0+to+8) = 442.336...

Volume of [solid #2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=revolve%20area%20between%20x%20%3D%20y%5E%282%2F3%29%20and%20x%20%3D%200%20and%20y%20%3D%208%20around%20x%20%3D%208%20from%200%20to%208) = 442.336...

Comment: I agree with your intuition - the one around x=8 should be larger.

Comment: Maybe you could show your work, how you came to the answers you checked.

Comment: Oh, the answers I got were totally wrong. I'm still working on the problem actually. I just noticed that on WolframAlpha it gave the same answer. That's what sparked my question.

Comment: Frankly askin is it related to moment of inetia as for cylinders its $1/2ml^2$

Comment: Is the volume signed?